# function that completes operations on files after a certain period of time

Tags: python

I'm a little stuck with a function I'm writing. Let's say we have a dictionary and a list as below:

```
dict = {".txt": 10, ".docx": 100"}
files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.docx"]
```

Let's also say that each file in the list has a certain age, `file1_age= 9, file2_age = 13, file3_age = 87`. i.e. they were created 9, 13, and 87 minutes ago respectively.

I'm trying to connect the files in the list with their respective file format in the dictionary. I then want to say `if age of file > number in dictionary: do this` It's essentially saying, leave the files as they are until they are a certain age and then do this thing with the files. Some pseudo code below.

```
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(dict.keys()):
        if file_age > dic.values():
            do this
```

Any help on how to do this would be much appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with the example you've provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
for file in files:
    ending = "." + file.split(".")[-1]
    if ending in dict:
        if file_age > dict[ending]:
            #do this
```

Comment: You need to show how to set `file_age` from `file`.

Comment: `file.split(".")[-1]` would be better, in case there are names like `foo.bar.txt`